# Button to delete a user account

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that produces a list of user accounts from mysql db.  I would like a button that can delete a user from this list.

Here is my form:

```
<td><form action="empdelete.php">
 <?php echo "<input type='text' name='employee' value='".$employee['username']."'/><button type='submit' class='btn btn-default'>Delete</button>"?>
        </form></td>;
```

Here is my empdelete.php:

```
<?php 
if($_POST['submit'])
{
    mysql_connect("host","username","pword") or die(mysql_error()); 


   mysql_select_db("db") or die(mysql_error()); 


   $username = $_POST['username'];


   $result=mysql_query("DELETE FROM employee WHERE username='$username'") or die(mysql_error()); 

    //confirm
   echo "Employee Deleted"; 
}
?>
```

The table name is employee and the column name is username.  It doesn't seem to be working.. any suggestions?

Comment: you have no input bearing the `username` POST, you have `employee`

Comment: Sorry - I am very new at this.  Would you be able to explain a little more for me please?

Comment: `<input type='text' name='employee'` name = EMPLOYEE, `$username = $_POST['username'];` should be `$username = $_POST['employee'];`

Comment: Your code is unsafe, anyone using your web app can delete the whole database by entering _' or true or '_ as a user name. Read up on SQL injection.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: Thank you - I am familiar with SQL injections but don't need to be concerned about them for this small project :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a normal link and pass the username as a GET parameter

```
<?php 
    echo '<a href="empdelete.php?username='.$employee['username'].'">Delete</a>';
?>
```

And then in your PHP you can take the value and make your delete

```
<?php 

if($_GET['username']) {

    mysql_connect("host","username","pword") or die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("db") or die(mysql_error()); 

    $username = $_GET['username'];
    $result=mysql_query("DELETE FROM employee WHERE username='$username'") or die(mysql_error()); 

    echo "Employee Deleted"; 

}

?>
```

** be careful though - your approach leaves you open to SQL injection attacks, you should read up about these **

Comment: Thank you Chris.  I tried that and unfortunately got this error message:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'username'];?>'' at line 1

Comment: Can you show me what HTML you're using now for the delete link?

Comment: THAT WORKED.  Thank you sooooo much :)

Comment: Great ... but do make sure you read up about SQL injection attacks. It may sound boring but it'll save you stress in the future.

Comment: Thanks.. I am familiar with SQL injection this is just a small project.  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In the `<input>` you have `name="employee"`, therefore you need `$username = $_POST['employee'];`

Also, your program is vulnerable to SQL injection.
When you do this:

```
   $username = $_POST['username'];


   $result=mysql_query("DELETE FROM employee WHERE username='$username'")
```

you need to sanitize the `$username` variable. Start with this question to learn about SQLi:

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)